# How to transfer MAP.values into Arrays efficiently?

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, dictionary

In the example below, you see some noisy but straightforward implementation.

**Initial Situation**

We have an initial Array with repeating information.

```
const listArray = [
  { songBy: 'George Michael',  uid: 'A',  whatEver: 12},
  { songBy: 'George Michael',  uid: 'A',  whatEver: 13},
  { songBy: 'George Michael',  uid: 'A',  whatEver: 14},
  { songBy: 'Michael Jackson', uid: 'B',  whatEver: 12},
  { songBy: 'Michael Jackson', uid: 'B',  whatEver: 16},
]
```

**STEP 1**

We create a new Map because we **distinctly** want to save artist names, which means → no artist-name-repetitions (and we also want to get rid of the third column, by the way).

We need to use `songBy` as key, for some reason. We change it within the value into `name`.

```
const listMap = new Map();

listArray.forEach(
  row => listMap.set(
   row.songBy, {name: row.songBy, uid: row.uid}
  )
);
```

**STEP 2**

Finally, we need an array with its values:

```
const distinctListArray: Array<any> = [];

listMap.forEach(value => distinctListArray.push(value));
```

So we achieve a result as an Array of distinct objects in the form of:

```
[
  name: string
  uid: string
]
```

**Question:**

To my mind, this implementation is too noisy and not so elegant. There are too many steps and too many variables. (This example here is a simplified version of a real code I cannot share).

Is there a way to simplify that code and make it more efficient?

EDIT: [See online: TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=13&ssc=1&pln=15&pc=57#code/MYewdgzgLgBANgS2gQQE6oIYE8YF4YDaAUDDAN4wTgDmAQlgFwwDkA4gKYirXswCyCYAAsM7OMwA0pAK4IAJk2bJJpAO4ioAUQBu7VEwCMAJgC%20EkuUo16ijlx79BIsSpiyFLZVJjqMW3fowBgDMZhYUVGB0jCx23LwCwqLi3u6KXmoaOnqGACxhpBHWMcyJznAwAFIYwADWkSppLLSuvv45QabmhVZRNixlyVU19eCN8oot3m3ZgQYAbGEAukREoJCwiNB8GAAOeDBg7Kr8ewAUAJQA3KtbUGiYWAB0AGZcmjVCZ6ggJ7gAfPAkFAdrsnhB2FBvr9wcUpGQwBgALbsJg-VSwvpYKRNdFPdwmC7XVbraAwOTAhBgYBQAAywIe2CYjKwAB4MGAsID8AQljciHdQa93p8ztoMHBpLwAeTKdS6Qz0NgnrtpBAvuLJewifyLEA)

Comment: Your current approach appears to drop all songs by duplicate artists, leaving only one by each. Is that deliberate?

Comment: sorry, I did not understand, because there are no songs in the `listArray` above

Comment: Well, whatever those objects are - eg, your current approach would result in only two objects, from the input of 5. Did you mean to entirely drop the rest?

Comment: You can see the whole example here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=13&ssc=1&pln=15&pc=57#code/MYewdgzgLgBANgS2gQQE6oIYE8YF4YDaAUDDAN4wTgDmAQlgFwwDkA4gKYirXswCyCYAAsM7OMwA0pAK4IAJk2bJJpAO4ioAUQBu7VEwCMAJgC+EkuUo16ijlx79BIsSpiyFLZVJjqMW3fowBgDMZhYUVGB0jCx23LwCwqLi3u6KXmoaOnqGACxhpBHWMcyJznAwAFIYwADWkSppLLSuvv45QabmhVZRNixlyVU19eCN8oot3m3ZgQYAbGEAukREoJCwiNB8GAAOeDBg7Kr8ewAUAJQA3KtbUGiYWAB0AGZcmjVCZ6ggJ7gAfPAkFAdrsnhB2FBvr9wcUpGQwBgALbsJg-VSwvpYKRNdFPdwmC7XVbraAwOTAhBgYBQAAywIe2CYjKwAB4MGAsID8AQljciHdQa93p8ztoMHBpLwAeTKdS6Qz0NgnrtpBAvuLJewifyLEA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Convert the list to `[key, value]` pairs using `Array.map()`, and then create the map from the list. Convert the `Map` back to an array by applying `Array.from()` to the `Map.values()` iterator ([TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBANgS2gQQE6oIYE8YF4YDaAUDDAN4wTgDmAQlgFwwDkA4gKYirXswCyCYAAsM7OMwA0pAK4IAJk2bJJpAO4ioAUQBu7VEwCMAJgC+EkuUo16ijlx79BIsSpiyFLZVJjqMW3fowBgDMZhYUVGB0jCx23LwCwqLi3u6KXmoaOnqGACxhpBHWMcyJznAwAFIYwADWkSppLLSuvv45QabmhVZRNixlyVU19eCN8oot3m3ZgQYAbGEAukREoJCwckhQCGDAUAAy22iYOPgn2AB0AGaoIAC2ABQWYOyq-BgADo+IKOhX9y+j0eRT6WCk7hgJgAlHgAHwwCykAiRaJSChgDD3dhMVH0CHyKFLaEWaGXbQYODSdgQR4kklrcBUODsS5wEDUR5baC7fZHP6nBmkIA)):

```js
const listArray = [{"songBy":"George Michael","uid":"A","whatEver":12},{"songBy":"George Michael","uid":"A","whatEver":13},{"songBy":"George Michael","uid":"A","whatEver":14},{"songBy":"Michael Jackson","uid":"B","whatEver":12},{"songBy":"Michael Jackson","uid":"B","whatEver":16}]

const distinctListArray = Array.from(
  new Map(listArray.map(({ songBy, uid }) => 
    [songBy, { name: songBy, uid }]
  )).values()
)

console.log(distinctListArray)
```